# implementing OTP setup in React-native EXPO app

Tags: one-time-password

I am trying to receive a OTP in mobile device as i press submit button providing Phone number.Then on entering the OTP, the app should verify the device.
Could anybody guide me through this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Suman, this post is likely to get down-voted as off-topic, you need to find an example and start implementing this yourself, then when you hit specific errors, then ask for help providing your code and a clear question of how to get past your specific error, a good starting point for you could be found here https://github.com/tttstudios/react-native-otp-input

Comment: Thanks Nigel. will look into the link you provided and be back if i find any other issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.